# Run an Ajax request on a URL blocked for detecting Adblocker (Ghostery)

Tags: javascript, ajax, url, adblock

I need some simple code for detecting a blocked url.

[SethWhite](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3803371/sethwhite) has said: `You could also try to run an ajax request on a URL blocked by an adblocker. If it succeeds, there's no adblocker, if it fails, there's an adblocker.`

I can use [microajax](https://code.google.com/p/microajax/) to do this in the following way:

```
microAjax("/resource/url", function (res) {
  alert (res);
});
```

How I can call `window.open` if the request does not succeed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For microAjax, look up its documentation. I'd imagine in the response you can find the response code. If the code is `200` it's a success, and you can run `window.open()`. Otherwise, the request is likely being blocked.

```javascript
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if(request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 200 ) {
        console.log('No blocker');
    }
    else if(request.readyState === 4 && request.status === 0){
        console.log('Blocker exists');
    }
};

request.open("GET","pathTo/ads.html");
request.send();
```

This uses a local URL; I initially thought using external URLs was a good idea, but if they're made invalid by their owners you'll get false positives.

I tested this using Adblock Plus and it works. If this is a URL blocked by *Ghostery*, it should work as well; otherwise, you can try different URLs to see what's blocked.

You could also do this with jQuery's `$.ajax` function, but I gravitate towards vanilla JavaScript.