# How to detect adblock without changing or refreshing URL

Tags: ajax, adblock

I am using "adframe" library to detect adblock and it works just fine.

However, I am having an issue in a webpage that loads content through AJAX.

If the visitor enters to this page with adblock enabled, then the library detects it and the content is not displayed, but if the user enters to this page with adblock disabled, then the content is shown and ALL FUTURE content loaded through AJAX will be shown regardless the user enables adblock or not while he is on this page and that is my problem.

I am trying to detect adblock in the same URL, while AJAX functions are being executed.

Bellow is one of the functions... is it posible to detect adblock in between??

```
function action1(time,id_object)
{
    if(time != -1){
        $("#time_object").html(time);
        time2 = time - 1;
        id_object2 = id_object;
        count = setTimeout('action1(time2,id_object2);', 1000);
    }
    else
    {
        if(id_object != 0)
        {
             clearTimeout(count);
            $('#feedback').modal('show');
            $.ajax({
                async:true,
                dataType: "html",
                type: "POST",
                data: {id_object: id_object},
                contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                url: "site/show_object.php",
                beforeSend:function(){
                    $('#feedback').html(loading);

                },
                success:function(data){
                    $('#feedback').html(data);
                    count = setTimeout('webpage3()',60000); 
                },
                timeout:20000, 
                error:function(){
                location.href= 'webpage4';
                }
            }); 
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            next();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following snippet and check console for message

HTML

```
<div id="addBlockerDiv">
    <div class="adBanner" style="background-color: transparent;height:1px;width:1px;">
       &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
window.onload = function(){
     if(document.getElementById("addBlockerDiv").clientHeight > 0) {
        console.log('adblock not present');
    } else {
        console.log('adblock present');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @front_end_dev, the way I see it, your script will work only when the page is loaded for the first time or when it's refreshed, but my problem is that i can't detect adblock when ajax content is being loaded in the same URL

Comment: @user289877 Take reference from this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33812704/run-an-ajax-request-on-a-url-blocked-for-detecting-adblocker-ghostery/33813919